# Minimum Membership fee is ignored during renewal in Backoffice

Tags: civimember

I have a simple question about membership fees. I have configured a membership type with 15€ monthly. 
When I try to renew the membership in Civi Backend I get the amount prefilled, but I can change it to e.g. 10€ and book the membership extension.

I expected to get an error message or at least a warning that I try to extend the membership with less than the minimum fee.

Is there a way to visualize these information?

Thanks for your help!
Said

Comment: No one an idea? Or is the question not clear?